# What is JCoDestinationManager.getDestination for?

Tags: java, jco

What is `JCoDestinationManager.getDestination` for?

```
private JCoDestination getConnection(String connectionPropertyFileName)
{
    if (log.isInfoEnabled())
    {
        log.info("Inside SAPJavaDefaultAdapter/getConnection()");
    }

    try
    {
        return JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(connectionPropertyFileName);
    }
    catch (JCoException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your question can very well be answer by taking the time to grab any form of documentation..

Answer (score -1):

Straight from the [manual](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoDestinationManager.html):

> Call this method to get an instance of a destination, on which you
>   need to execute a function module.